# How to do "Today Minus Date Field" in Google Data Studio?

Tags: datetime, looker-studio

I have column `long_term_remaining_days`, and I want to create a Date field which
will be calculate `TODAY` - `long_term_remaining_days` and in this way will display a Date, for example `1 Jun 2020`.

I tried to do as in Excel and used the formula below, but it doesn't work:

```
TODAY() - long_term_remaining_days
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way it can be achieved is by using the new [`PARSE_DATE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9739156), [`UNIX_DATE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9736756) and [`CURRENT_DATE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9736967) functions (introduced in the [17 Sep 2020 update to Dates and Times](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6311467#sep-17-2020)).

### 1) `Calculated Date`

Copy-paste the [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below which converts [`CURRENT_DATE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9736967) to [`UNIX_DATE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9736756) (the number of days since epoch, 01 Jan 1970) and subtracts `long_term_remaining_days` (where `long_term_remaining_days` represents the respective Number field), after which it's converted to a **UNIX_TIMESTAMP** by multiplying with 86,400 (seconds in a day) before then being recognised as a Google Data Studio date using the [`PARSE_DATE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9739156) function:

```
PARSE_DATE(
    "%s",
    CAST(((UNIX_DATE(CURRENT_DATE())-long_term_remaining_days)*86400)AS TEXT))
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/a7f30e82-a1b0-448b-a3de-b6f396475306) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]